# How do I assert a contract is inactive (archived) in a scenario?

Tags: daml

If I wanted to validate that a contract is active, I could simply fetch it in a Scenario:

```
template Something
  with
    party : Party
  where
    signatory party

    nonconsuming choice DoStuff : ()
      controller party
        do
          return ()


myTest = scenario do
  someone <- getParty "Someone"
  submit someone do
    cid <- create Something with party = someone 
    exercise cid DoStuff
    fetch cid  -- would fail if the DoStuff choice was consuming
```

How do I assert the opposite?

```
template Something
  with
    party : Party
  where
    signatory party

    choice DoStuff : ()
      controller party
        do
          return ()


myTest = scenario do
  someone <- getParty "Someone"
  submit someone do
    cid <- create Something with party = someone 
    exercise cid DoStuff
    fetch cid  -- fails the scenario, as it should, but that's what I want to check for
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code shows that you can chain the `cid` into an appropriate scope to allow a `submitMustFail` to operate in the way intended:

```
myTest = scenario do
  someone <- getParty "Someone"
  cid <- submit someone do
    create Something with party = someone
  submit someone do
    exercise cid DoStuff
  submitMustFail someone do
    fetch cid  -- would fail if the DoStuff choice was consuming
```

Comment: Do we need any declaration for 'submitMustFail' at the top? @Fil